# Trouble after mainboard replacement

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, motherboard, bios

the problem is the following. Either my gfx or my mainboard had a problem on the previous pc, so I replaced everything (except HDD, Tower and DVD drive) since I figured I might as well upgrade.

Obviously windows 7 won't boot now. The new mainboard is a gigabyte ga-z170-hd3p.

I figured I could just throw in a linux live CD to copy data from my old HDD, but I've tried three versions so far (from USB and CD - Slax, PuppyLinux with UEFI support and systemrescuecd) and the booting stops when they attempt to load the Kernel. Puppy linux even got past that point and then the screen went black.

On top of it, my previous SATA DVD-RW-Drive isn't recognized by the new bios, so I'm working with an USB external now.

I've tried working from the Windows CMD in the system repair options in order to attempt to replace the mainboard drivers manually, or to copy important data manually from there to an external HDD but these don't show up in the list of drives.

Oh, and did I mention that with the Windows install cd, it doesn't even let me reinstall the damn thing cause it says it can't find the drivers for the DVD-Drive?

I've also switched support in BIOS from uefi only to legacy only and back and it didn't change a thing.

Summary of problems:

- Linux Live Distributions didn't work so far.
- Windows tells me it doesn't find the drivers for my DVD-Drive.
- Can't access USB devices from CMD (I figure this might be normal)
- DVD-Drive doesn't work (replaced the cable already, it's not that)

Comment: Will it boot into safe mode?

Comment: If you can get into safe mode, run "sysprep.exe" found in C:\Windows\Sysprep folder, when sysprep opens select OOBE and Generalize box and Restart option, then OK button. It will grind a while then It should restart into windows normally, this removes all drivers from the install, W7 will install what it has upon reboot, then you can install any missing.

Comment: I would just reinstall W7, moving it to a new motherboard will deactivate the license key anyhow.

Comment: I fixed the problems with simple steps, and reinstalled windows as Moab suggested. This can be closed now (don't know if I can do it myself, am new here). Anyway, thanks for the help!